# Flow of Today's Recommended Style

Tags: style, clarity, rhythm

I know I've already posted many questions about the rhythm and flow of prose, but now I am asking a sort of specific question about the principles of style in relation to such things.

All the style guides I've read recommend concise and vigorous writing, and many of the articles on flow I've read recommend variety in sentence length and structure. So then, do concise, vigorous sentences, when varied from on another, tend to flow smoothly? Or does something special need to be done with word choice?

**The real question is whether concise, vigorous prose flows with a cadence inherent to its own style, so that aiming for any deliberate effect is unnecessary or inviable.** It seems that striving to produce an effect deliberately in a sentence tends to convolute its word choice.

If this is the case, then how is it even possible for anyone to produce a work such as the King James Bible, whose prose is obviously not convoluted, though hard for many to understand? This is not a question about other people's work, but how a person is able to produce their own rhythmic work. If writing prose is all about pruning every sentence and making it forceful, and varying it from the previous one, then how does anyone produce any deliberate rhythm at all?

I know I've asked questions like this in the past, but I'm not satisfied with the answers, because they don't address these phenomena as precisely as I wish. Most of the time, when I aim for deliberate rhythmic effects, I get garbage that sounds like junk, and many times, when I focus only on being clear and concise, my words lack grace anyway.

I would like somebody to help me understand these things so I can write what I want. Once I get these things about prose style resolved in my head, I can focus on other aspects of writing.

Thank you.

Comment: I think what you're aiming for is more like the rhythm of poetry. If you want to write poetry, or certain kinds of flowery literary fiction, more power to you - I'm not that good at it. It comes off as fake or artificial when I try.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but all I do is play it by ear. I write stuff and try to make it sound good, then I rewrite and try to make it sound better. I'm not sure how much this can be understood without experience - as you've said, no-one has given an answer you're happy with to any of your previous questions on this topic, and it sounds like you're waiting for that answer before continuing. Stop waiting. For all it's a cliche, write. Write more. Read. Rewrite. Figure the prose style out as you go.

Comment: The King James Bible hardly fits within any modern style regardless....